# Stackblitz on Firefox Bundling just spins

Tags: firefox, angular-material

I'm running Firefox 45.4 and cannot upgrade past that (at work).  Opening Angular Material examples on Stackblitz just results in a perpetual "Bundling app..." spinner that never finishes, never renders anything.  Now that all the Angular Material docs force you to use Stackblitz to see the examples, I am completely unable to see any of the doc examples.  Wow...who's bright idea was that?

Comment: What's your question? If it is a bug, please raise an issue at Angular material issue tracker

Comment: The question is: does anyone know if StackBlitz requires some recent browser version feature?  There's no info there about any minimum browser requirements.  Thank you for the suggestion on Angular material - I have entered an issue there.

Comment: @user3174133 Can you try contacting Stackblitz Support? Their support email address is support@stackblitz.com

Comment: Yes, will do.  Thank you for the email.

Comment: FYI:  "Your message wasn't delivered to support@stackblitz.com because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail."   Did this site fold or something?

Comment: @user3174133 I got that email address from Stackblitz's Terms of Service. Scroll down all the way, where you should see "Contacing us" header: https://stackblitz.com/terms-of-service